# Developer Story set to private, but still can see View my Developer Story which leads to 404 page

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, developer-story

I was watching the Developer Story of others and tried to look at the Developer Story of a mod [Bolt Clock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock), but whenever I click on it, it leads me to a 404 error page.

I asked him and he said he made his Developer Story private. Then why are others seeing that link? According to Bolt Clock there should be no link or button as he made his Developer Story private, so why is it there?

Yes I know, Developer Story is in a testing phase, but I'm still thinking it's a bug and there should be no button if the Developer Story is private.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. This button has been the source of much confusion and will be removed with our next production build :).